# capitalize first letter of each line using regex

Tags: python, regex, string

I am trying to make the first letter of every line an upper case

I am using the following regular expression

```
ModCon = re.sub('^[a-z]{1}', lambda x: x.upper(), ModCon)
```

nothing happens when I run the program.

Comment: And what is your *input* then? Does it contain newlines?

Comment: @MartijnPieters  yes it does .. it is a file that has 2 lines for now , i am supposed to remove all double spaces to single and capitalize every letter at the beginning of every line

Comment: Note that `{1}` is *always* a useless construct.  `ANYTHING{1}` is always the same as `ANYTHING`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `^` anchor only matches the very start of your input string. If you want it to match after each newline, you need to give it the `re.M` or `re.MULTILINE` flag too:

```
ModCon = re.sub('^[a-z]', lambda x: x.group().upper(), ModCon, flags=re.M)
```

I removed the `{1}` part; it is implicit, without a repetition indicator the character set only matches *one* character.

The replacement function is passed a [`Match` object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#match-objects), so you need to pull out the matched string by calling the `.group()` method.

Comment: I am getting an error that i think is concerned with the function upper, am I presenting the function in a correct way?

Comment: @HayaRaed: Ah, no. A match object is passed in, not the matched string. Updated.

Comment: so the function group(), it group the matching into a string?

Comment: `.group()` without arguments returns the string that was matched (group 0).

Answer (score 1):

The variable x in the lambda function is not of type string, but it is a <type '_sre.SRE_Match'>. In order to get the matching string, you need to `call x.group()`.

Thus (also using the hints in the other answers), the following script works fine:

```
import re
ModCon= "what is your favorite color?\nred"
ModCon = re.sub('^[a-z]', lambda x: x.group().upper(), ModCon, flags=re.M)
print (ModCon)
```